# Reasons for .ssh/rc file not to be executed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have a remote machine with Ubuntu 16.04.3 running. I want my `~/.ssh/rc` file to be executed each time when I log in via ssh. However, it is silently skipped. There are no error messages (or even any rc-related messages) neither in `ssh -vvvv` from client side nor in `/var/log/auth.log` from server side.

The sshd option `PermitUserRC` for sshd is set to `Yes` (it is not explicitly mentioned in the config file, but its default value is `Yes`).

Permissions are 700 for both `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/rc`.

The same client side setup works on other versions of Ubuntu (12.04 and 14.04).

I have sudo access to the machine, but cannot reboot it or restart sshd. (Though admins may do it if I find a cause).

Any reasons why it may happen?

Answer (score 12):

This is the OpenSSH 7.3p1 code for invoking `.ssh/rc`. It's from  "session.c". The rc file is invoked by a function named `do_rc_files()`. All of this code runs in the server. All of the options referenced are taken from `sshd_config`, along with the `authorized_keys` file entry for the key which authenticated the session (if key authentication was used).

```
/*
 * Run $HOME/.ssh/rc, /etc/ssh/sshrc, or xauth (whichever is found
 * first in this order).
 */
static void
do_rc_files(Session *s, const char *shell)
{

    [...]

        /* ignore _PATH_SSH_USER_RC for subsystems and admin forced commands */
        if (!s->is_subsystem && options.adm_forced_command == NULL &&
            !no_user_rc && options.permit_user_rc &&
            stat(_PATH_SSH_USER_RC, &st) >= 0) {
                snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "%s -c '%s %s'",
                    shell, _PATH_BSHELL, _PATH_SSH_USER_RC);
                if (debug_flag)
                        fprintf(stderr, "Running %s\n", cmd);
                f = popen(cmd, "w");
                if (f) {
                        if (do_xauth)
                                fprintf(f, "%s %s\n", s->auth_proto,
                                    s->auth_data);
                        pclose(f);
                } else
                        fprintf(stderr, "Could not run %s\n",
                            _PATH_SSH_USER_RC);
        } else if (stat(_PATH_SSH_SYSTEM_RC, &st) >= 0) {
            ...
```

`do_rc_files()` itself is invoked like this:

```
    if (!options.use_login)
            do_rc_files(s, shell);
```

So, this tells us:

1. No rc files are invoked if the sshd option "UseLogin" was set.
2. .ssh/rc is not invoked if the session is invoking a subsystem. This affects SFTP sessions for example.
3. .ssh/rc is not invoked if the session is subject to a `ForceCommand` setting in `sshd_config` (but not for forced commands from `authorized_keys`).
4. .ssh/rc is not invoked if the `authorized_keys` option "no-user-rc" was set (or "restrict", which implies no-user-rc).
5. .ssh/rc is not invoked if the `sshd_config` option "PermitUserRC" option is set to "no".
6. .ssh/rc is not invoked if it's not present, relative to the user's home directory.

If OpenSSH decides to invoke .ssh/rc, it will end up invoking this command:

```
$SHELL -c '/bin/sh .ssh/rc'
```

where "$SHELL" is the user's login shell. This will fail if the user's shell doesn't accept the "-c" option to run a command. It could also fail if `/bin/sh` is missing or not working correctly.